# Vertx 3.6.3: Unable to launch HTTPS server with PFX option

Tags: java, https, vert.x, pfx

I am using Vertx `3.6.3`. I am trying to run an HTTPS server verticle, but unfortunately, verticle is not getting deployed. Could you please let me know where I am doing it wrong?

Here is my verticle:

**HTTPSVerticle:**

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.net.PfxOptions;

public class HTTPSVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> httpsServerStarted) throws Exception {
        int port = config().getJsonObject("http", new JsonObject()).getInteger("port", 8000);
        boolean useSsl = config().getJsonObject("http", new JsonObject()).getBoolean("useSsl", false);
        String sslCertPath = config().getJsonObject("http", new JsonObject()).getString("sslCertPath", "");
        String sslCertPassword = config().getJsonObject("http", new JsonObject()).getString("sslCertPassword", "");

        HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions();

        System.out.println(useSsl);

        if (useSsl)
            httpServerOptions
                    .setSsl(true)
                    //.setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED)
                    .setPfxTrustOptions(
                            new PfxOptions().setPath(sslCertPath).setPassword(sslCertPassword)
                    );

        vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions).requestHandler(httpReq -> {
            httpReq.response().end("Hello encrypted world");
        }).listen(port, fut -> {
            if (fut.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Verticle now listening on port: " + port);
                httpsServerStarted.complete();
            }
            else {
                httpsServerStarted.fail(fut.cause());
                System.out.println("Error while starting HTTP server");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

**TestHTTPSVerticle:**

```
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class TestHTTPSVerticle {
    private static Vertx vertx;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(TestContext context) {
        DeploymentOptions opts = new DeploymentOptions()
                .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("http", new JsonObject()
                        .put("useSsl", true)
                        .put("sslCertPath", "test.pfx")
                        .put("sslCertPassword", "abcd")));

        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(HTTPSVerticle.class.getName(), opts, context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown(TestContext context) {
        vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHttpsServerMessage(TestContext context) {
        Async async = context.async();

        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");

        vertx.createHttpClient().get(8000, "localhost", "/loremipsum", respHandler -> respHandler.bodyHandler(respBody -> {
            System.out.println(respBody);
            context.assertTrue(respBody.toString().equals("Hello encrypted world"));
            async.complete();
        })).end();
    }
}
```

Its not letting me submit it without elaborating, so redundant elaboration follows:

1. I am using vertx config mechanism to fetch `port`, `useSsl`, `sslCertPath` and `sslCertPassword`
2. I am using `HttpServerOptions` for configuring SSL settings for http server
3. When server is started successfully, it should print `Verticle now listening on port: 8000`
4. In case, server fails to start, it should print `Error while starting HTTP server`

But, It never invokes listen's handler with **AsyncResult**.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you file an issue in [eclipse-vertx](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/new) repo?

Comment: I went ahead and [filed the bug](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/2867). It's fixed in master  and 3.7 branch. 3.7 should be released in the coming weeks.